'Unable to reach the server' immediately after installing Civi on Backdrop (only at Civihosting)
After installing Backdrop 1.28.3 (and the newly released 1.29) & then installing CiviCRM I get 'Unable to reach the server' when clicking on the 'Configuration' link.  This is on the Civihosting.com shared server setup. I have tried Civi releases 5.74.4, 5.77 and 5.78beta, and also tried separate databases and a single Backdrop database. Still the same problem. There are no messages in the Civilog except for the first install message. In the Backdrop log there is

"Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException: DB Error: already exists in CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler() (line 973 of /home/kewguild/www/try/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php)."

In the Civihosting log there are a number of messages like this:

"try.kewguild.org.uk [Mon Sep 16 11:01:41 2024] [error] [pid 5992] mod_negotiation.c(1286): [client 51.7.138.170:65291] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/kewguild/www/try/civicrm (None could be negotiated)."

I have posted a message in the Backdrop forum and also had some support from Civihosting but without a solution so far. I should emphasise that on another hosting site, using cPanel, that this problem doesn't exist. Also, the Civihosting site is presently running Civi with Drupal 7. As a sanity check, I setup another Drupal 7 system on Civihosting, installed Civi - no problem at all.

Fix supplied by David at CiviHosting, which is to add the following to the .htaccess file.  Thanks David!
Options -MultiViews
This was discussed in the Backdrop forum here and also was answered here CiviCRM installation (Backdrop) incomplete
